# How can Powershell copy an entire folder structure but exclude one folder and its contents

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

This seems like a simple operation but I can't figure out how to get Powershell to copy an entire folder structure from one location to another but exclude one folder (called 'connections') and its contents.

I've tried combining Copy-Item and Get-ChildItem like so

```
cpi (gci folder1 -Exclude connections) folder2  -recurse
```

but it seems the -recurse parameter overwrites the -exclude parameter and the connections folder and its contents are copied. Without -recurse the contents of the folders I do want copied are ignored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why that isn't working, it seems to behave correctly on my machine.

You could always pipe to `Copy-Item`:

```
Get-ChildItem folder1 | where { !(($_ -is [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]) -and ($_.Name -eq "connections")) } | Copy-Item -Destination folder2 -Recurse
```

The advantage of this is that you can just get PowerShell to print out the output after:

```
Get-ChildItem folder1 | where { !(($_ -is [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]) -and ($_.Name -eq "connections")) }
```

That way you can check exactly what is getting copied (i.e. is the "connections" folder missing?)

Comment: There is a caveat with this that it could omit a file named "connections" although that is not likely. Also avoid using aliases like `dir` in answers as some users might not be familiar with them.